# Как задать цвет элемента select > option при наведении на него курсора?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, css, select, вёрстка

select содержит option, нужно задать цвет при наведении на option курсора, для примера, на картинке у option'а как-то задан оранжевый бэкграунд и белый color

```
< select>
< option>1< /option>
< option>2< /option>
< /select>
```

[image]

Еще интересует способ покраски бордера у option.

Answer (score 1):

То, что ты хочешь видеть при наведении мышки на элемент, прописывается псевдоклассом :hover
border в том числе

[Смотрим тут](http://jsfiddle.net/mjjLdcfd/)

Comment: Попробуйте это проделать с 

     <select>
       <option>1</option>
       <option>1</option>
     </select>

и у Вас ничего не получится. Вообще, с помощью чистого CSS это сделать нельзя (поправьте, если можно).

Я уже давно для таких целей использую библиотеки вроде:
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/, https://select2.github.io/

Comment: разбираю селект2, прикрутил select2.css и select2.min.js, можете сказать, как добраться до параметра цвета в "ховер", или, может, там ховер не используются даже?

Comment: @mr_blond97, эти селекторы отвечают за цвет hover: 

     .select2-results .select2-highlighted {
        background: #3875d7;
        color: #fff;
     }

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/fecs9d9L/